# Export Images to MS Word in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, export

I am trying to export images to MS-Word document in Windows forms application.

Below is the list of data to be exported in Word document

```
TestCaseName TestStatus Screenshot ScreenshotPath 
TC001         Pass          Yes     C:\\tc001.jpg
TC002         Pass          Yes     C:\\tc002.jpg
```

I tried using the below code to export the list in Word from the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/766028/How-to-export-winform-datagrid-to-word-landscape).

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Word Documents (*.doc)|*.doc";
            sfd.FileName = "time.doc";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {              
                DataGridView newdgv = new DataGridView();
                newdgv = dataGridView1.RemoveEmptyColumns();
                ToCsV(newdgv, sfd.FileName); 
            }         

 }

private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
        {
            string stOutput = "";
            // Export titles:
            string sHeaders = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
                sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t\t";            
            stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
            // Export data.
            for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount; i++)
            {
                string stLine = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
                stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";              
            }
            Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
            byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

I tried adding the below code to add single image in word using Interop

```
doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\tc001.jpg");
```

But How to add the screenshot images in the export list method to Word document.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: Define `Word document`: Do you mean Office XML, or old & busted MSWord?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Did the AddPictures method work for you, correctly? If not, how not. If yes, why does knowing this method not help you?